# How to change app name displayed in Google Sign-in page using Firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

I have an iOS app with multiple targets where each target produces a separate app with unique bundle ids, names...

Authentication in the apps is managed by Firebase. There is one Firebase project where each of the targets has own app registered (there are Android versions of the apps as well).

The situation in firebase console:

[image]

The issue I am facing is Google sign-in page(after tapping Google sign-in button) is presenting the Project's Public-facing name in every app target.

An example of the sing-in screen:

[image]

So I have apps A, B, C and the sign-in message reads 'Sign in to continue to XYZ' (red box in the screenshots) which is quite strange. I'd be happier the message would be matching the app name where the user just opened the dialog.

The reason why we don't have multiple Firebase projects for every app is Firebase Analytics - so we have stats for all the apps (and platforms) merged at one place.

**Is there a way how to show, let's say, Product Name in the sign-in screen while keeping all targets under the one Firebase Project?**

PODs used:

```
Using Firebase (5.14.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.4.0)
Using FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.1.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.1.0)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.1.9)
Using FirebaseDynamicLinks (3.3.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.3.0)
Using FirebaseMessaging (3.2.2)
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.6)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.1)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.0.2)
```